# Why a apart of LoginViewController is hidden when adding it into NavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't understand this. On method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, When I set `self.window.rootViewController = <instance of LoginViewController>`, it shows full of Login screen as expectation. But when I add `LoginViewController` into `NavigationController` and then set `self.window.rootViewController = <instance of NavigationController>`, a part on the top of the Login screen is hidden?

[image: Before adding into NavigationController]

[image: After adding into NavigationController]

Comment: set navigation bar hidden. That top hidden part is for navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, upper area of the view is being covered by navigation bar so you can hide it with this code

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because, by default, the navigation controller has the navigation bar visible. To ensure that the navigation bar is hidden in your login screen, you should call in `viewDidLoad()` method of login screen view controller `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`